# 'Sick leave' and 'ill versus sick'

Tags: word-usage, register

We want to use the terms *ill* and *illness* in our software instead of *sick* (see also [Is there any difference between being ill and sick?](https://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/2/is-there-any-difference-between-being-ill-and-sick)), but I'm having difficulty finding a proper replacement for the term *sick leave*.

What can we use?
(which, to confuse things, is often defined as *leave of absence granted because of illness*)

Note: we have several kinds of official/authorized leave, so I can't use a generic 'leave' term.

Comment: Do you dislike the offerings at [thesaurus.com](http://www.thesaurus.com/browse/sick%20leave)?

Comment: @Davo I totally forgot that website existed ;-) But yes: *authorized leave* would be too broad because we have other kinds of authorized leave, and *excused absence* sounds a bit too informal as well.

Comment: How about medical leave?

Comment: *Sick leave* is a well-known and widely-used term. Is there a compelling reason not to use it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

"sick leave" is such a common construction that it may be the best option. Just because you use "ill" in other scenarios doesn't necessarily mean "sick leave" would be incorrect in its own right.

Example of mixing the two:

> Jeff: I didn't see Sally yesterday. Was she ill?

to which one could reply

> Mike: Yes, the took a sick day.

OR

> Mike: Yes, she was on sick leave.